# Set NodeJS's V8 engine's heapstack

Tags: javascript, node.js, heap-memory, v8

My program crashes when i try to pull "too much" (for the heap) data up from my postgressql db and place it in an array...

> JAVASCRIPT HEAP OUT OF MEMORY

The heap_size_limit in my PC is currently 1535115264 bytes or 1.42969 GB (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/v8.html) which is exactly the amount my app consumes - before it crashes each time.

But i really can't figure out how to change this limit?

I have tried with:

> --max_old_space_size=100000 (100 GB)
>
> --max_new_space_size=100000000 (100 GB)

max_old_space_size in generel works - but not regarding the heap size.
max_new_space_size doesn't seem to change any thing at all :-(

I also tried to play with other options - but without luck.

> --clever_optimizations
>
> --optimize_for_size
>
> --heap_profiler_trace_objects
>
> --typed_array_max_size_in_heap
>
> --stack_size
>
> --max_executable_size

https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md

Answer (score 1):

`--max_old_space_size` is the way to go. Don't go overboard with it; huge values probably won't work well. There have also been some fixes in recent V8 versions to better support huge heaps; I think Node 6.x is too old to contain those, so you might have more success with a newer version.

You don't need (and probably shouldn't set) any other flags. (You *definitely* don't want a 100GB new space!)

What do you mean by "works - but not regarding the heap size"?

Comment: i use --max_old_space_size with great succes in other scenarios... like spawning 36 node processes at a big AWS instance with 32, 64 or 128 GB memory. But regarding this heap thing - the argument doesn't change/help any thing at all. I just updated nodejs to the latest version 7.8 and it helped a tiny bit - 200mb more memory use - before the app crashes - again ... :-( I read some where - you have to make manually changes to the V8 engine source code - before some setting some arguments will actually have effect (may be in older version)? Why is it so diffecult to change!? :-((

Comment: No, you don't have to change the source in order for flags to take effect. -- Try using a (prerelease) Node version that contains a V8 built this year (5.7.x or 5.8.x).

Comment: I'm running the latest version of NodeJs 7.8.0. Why would i benefit by installing an old version (v. 5..?) of NodeJS?

Comment: A "prerelease Node version" that contains "V8 version 5.7.x or 5.8.x". Node 7.8 contains V8 5.5.

Comment: To be more specific, it is V8 5.8.x that introduces support for arbitrarily large heaps, see: https://v8project.blogspot.com/2017/02/one-small-step-for-chrome-one-giant.html